# Why BufferedReader reads just 1st row?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

This is a method for checking a word in a file, but the method only returns the word is in the first row, if a check a word from a second row it returns false

```java
public static boolean isWord(String file,String word) throws FileNotFoundException,IOException {
    boolean isWord=false;
    BufferedReader read=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String content;

    while((content=read.readLine()) != null) {
        if(content.contains(word)) {
            isWord=true;
        } else {
            isWord=false;
        }       
    }
    
}
    return isWord;  
}
```

Comment: I think you need to delete the `else` clause. You don't want to set `isWord` back to false if it has been set to true. Or you could just `return true` as soon as you find the word.

Comment: Your `while` loop reads every line in the file. After the loop terminates, `isWord` will be **true** only if the last line in the file contained the word you are searching for. Is that what you want?

Comment: I would really recommend debugging programs like this. There's no point asking if you haven't been through to check what happens yourself. This article outlines some great steps: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because if the file has 2 rows and the second is not a word, "isWord" is then assigned a "false" value. When you get to the return statement, "false" is the last assigned value and that is why you get a "false" value from the method if the second row has no word in it.